# WebView history

Tags: cocoa, webkit

When is a page added to the forward backward list in WebView?

I have [webview setMaintainsBackForwardList:YES], but [webview canGoBack] still returns NO after I do a couple of [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:request]. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe entries are only put onto this list when the user navigates. If you want to add items to this list programmatically, you'll need to send `addItem:` to the webView's backForwardList.