# Restore history and current page on resuming webview

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, history, bundle

I have a webview that I am navigating within. I have implemented go back and go forward. My problem is that when I return to the webview after visiting another activity, the history is lost i.e. the webview starts from the first url.

How do I code it so that after I call finish on the webview to swap to another activity on returning to the webview, the WebBackForwardList is restored and I am taken to the page I was on when I left the webview?

I have tried overriding onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState using webview.save/restoreState(bundle) but with no success.

I have achieved returning to the last page by saving the last url in preferences, but have been unable to restore the entire history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you reusing the webview?

The javadoc for restore() says:

> This method should be called to
>   restore the state of the WebView
>   before using the object. If it is
>   called after the WebView has had a
>   chance to build state (load pages,
>   create a back/forward list, etc.)
>   there may be undesirable side-effects.

so regenerating the webview object may help.

Other avenues to research:

- WebView.restore() calls list.addHistoryItem(item) without clearing the list, so if you have a webView that is getting *reused*, it may help to call webView.clearHistory() first before the restore().
- This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257909/webview-history) implies that there is a message you can send to the history list to add items.

Good luck , and please post back your progress.

--larry

Comment: I tried using restore, but with no luck. I think this may have been because of a bug in my program logic. As it turns out, I have completely re-written the UI of my program. Previously I was choosing to launch the webview activity from my options menu using startactivityforresult. I finished the webview just before returning the token result. Just before finishing, I would save the last url via webview.getURL() to my sharedpreferences and reopen the url on re-starting the activity. This method would only reload the last page visited and not the entire history.

Comment: With my new design, I have implemented tabview and therefore am able to retain the entire history through switching tabs (as long as the user does not press the back button to call onDestroy). For the purpose of my current design, I have no need to implement the restore history solution. Should I need to I will return to this thread. Thank you for your thoughts larham1, I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: I think that the linked SO answer refers to the iOS WebView, not Android's.